# How to properly send map from angular client to spring boot controller in request body? Received map is always empty

Tags: java, angular, spring, dictionary, controller

**Angular client** - httpClient sending request

```
const map: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
map.set('foo', 'bar');
this.http.post(address, map, httpOptions).subscribe(
  next => console.log('next: ' + next),
  error => console.log('error: ' + error),
  () => console.log('complete')
);
```

**Springboot server** - controller receiving request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void fooBar(@RequestBody Map<String, String> foo){
    System.out.println(foo.entrySet());  //<-- always empty
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to convert the Map to an array of key-value pairs, as it turns out,  Typescript maps cannot be used directly inside a http post body.

You can convert the map as follows:

```
const convMap = {};
map.forEach((val: string, key: string) => {
  convMap[key] = val;
});
this.http.post(apiBaseUrl + '/foobar', convMap, httpOptions).subscribe(
      next => console.log('next: ' + next),
      error => console.log('error: ' + error),
      () => console.log('complete')
);
```

In the back-end, your `System.out.println(foo.entrySet());` will output the following: [foo=bar]

Comment: `JSON.stringify(map)` and `consumes="application/json"` didn't help, still empty map

Comment: Typescript map not suitable for http post calls. I used directly the json data key value pair `const postBody = {"data1":var1,"data2":var2}` and it works like champ.